# Loading of data

Tags: c#

```
private void RevenueSummary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'accountingDataSet1.Revenue' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
   this.revenueTableAdapter.Fill(this.accountingDataSet1.Revenue);

   string strGEC = GEClabel.Text;

   fillByToolStripButton.PerformClick();
}
```

hi, I am having problems displaying the data after I add a new revenue item. It will be display in the database but not in the datagridview. It will only appear if I close the application and run it again.

Comment: How about binding the data to your grid again after you've updated it?? `MyDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataSet; MyDataGrid.DataBind();`

Comment: i tried using what u say. but however there no such method as DataBind().

Comment: Try MyDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataSet; MyDataGrid.Refresh();

Comment: thanks for the ans, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your code you are calling the fill method only when the form is Loaded (I am assuming `RevenueSummary_Load` method is to handle the load event of the form), this makes the `accountingDataSet1` to be filled only when your Form is loaded and thats why when you update the database its not reflected in the dataset.

There are two things you can do to solve this.

1) Employ a `ServiceBroker` that will [notify your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx) when the database is updated via SqlDependency  (I assume your Database has this facility).

2) The other simple method would be have a refresh button where you fill the `dataset` again.

3) Finally you can have a timer that fills the `dataset` on every interval

NOTE: Both [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) and [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/11gr1_db/appdev/dcn/dcn.htm) support Change Data Capture.

**Update**

I dont know if MS Access has any push notification feature. As i have searched over internet your only options are either to go with timer based database polling or Implement a `FileSystemWatcher` object to monitor whether your MS Access database file gets changed. 
[here is an example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/85917272-c488-4f88-812f-595b6de81b9c/) to this approach.

Comment: hi, how do i fill the dataset again? do u have any sample code

Comment: i am using Microsoft access (.mdb)